# Algorithm for generating a bracket model list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to make a simple recursive function that will generate a list of nested lists in Python.  The end result will represent a single elimination tournament bracket.  I'm hoping that creating a list like this will make it easy for me to generate what I need.  This will later be used to create models for tournament matches.

So if there is a tournament of 4 participants:

```
[[1,4],[2,3]]
```

Tournament of 7 participants:

```
[[1,[4,5]],[[2,7],[3,6]]]
```

Or a tournament of 8 participants:

```
[[[1,8],[4,5]],[[2,7],[3,6]]]
```

I haven't had an algorithms class yet (I'm hoping the class will end up helping with things like this) so I'm not completely sure how to approach this problem.  Below is my attempt so far.

```
def decide_rounds(list_to_fill, player_nums):
    if len(player_nums) < 3:
        for num in player_nums:
            list_to_fill.append(num)
        return

    left = []
    decide_rounds(left, ??????) #Tried passing various things to these with no avail.
    list_to_fill.append(left)
    right = []
    decide_rounds(right, ???????)
    list_to_fill.append(right)
```

Any help or explanation on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Currently I am calling the function like this:

```
rounds = []
decide_rounds(rounds, range(1, size +1))
print rounds
```

Comment: Try: http://ideone.com/RVe8SQ

Comment: @irrelephant surely that should be a answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @irrelephant Here is a 16 player: http://pastebin.com/sTT07iCj

Your original answer works if it is given a list in the correct order, which could perhaps be solved with a simple function of some sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
def divide(arr, depth, m):
    if len(complements) <= depth:
        complements.append(2 ** (depth + 2) + 1)
    complement = complements[depth]
    for i in range(2):
        if complement - arr[i] <= m:
            arr[i] = [arr[i], complement - arr[i]]
            divide(arr[i], depth + 1, m)

m = int(raw_input())

arr = [1, 2]
complements = []

divide(arr, 0, m)
print arr
```

We notice that for a bracket with 2^n players, the sum of every pair is the same number. For every pair, the right term is determined by the left element and the depth of the recursion, so we can just proceed by generating the array depth first. We memoize the complements to improve runtime just a bit. It works for any `m > 1` as it stops recursing once the complement is too large.

See it in action: http://ideone.com/26G1fB

Comment: Thank you!  This does exactly what I want.  The description makes sense.  Awesome.

Comment: Would you explain this algo a little bit? Or is there a place I can look at an explanation of what's going on here? Having trouble understanding exactly what is happening :)